# Pycharm - unresolved reference, Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module

Project structure:

- app.py
- utils/stack_parameters.py
- utils/**init**.py

from app.py I import stack_parameters

```
from utils.stack_parameters import StackParameters
```

[image: pycharm screenshot of error]

Pycharm is marking the import - what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: Is app.py in the project root dir? What is set as content root in your project structure? (Access this under Settings->Project->Project Structure). If not, you need to mark the directory where the app.py is as a 'sources root' (blue folder).

Comment: I had the sources root set at the utils level. I've set it to app.py folder and warning disappeared.